# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark repeating on cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've tried every single option available on this website for this problem but none of them seems to be working.
If I scroll down I see the checkmark. If I scroll back up the positioning of my selection is not the same.
So as the problem is the same I wanted to open this question for one more time as a fresh start. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (![selectedDX containsObject:myMutArray[indexPath.row]])
    {
        [selectedDX addObject:myMutArray[indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedDX containsObject:myMutArray[indexPath.row]]) {
        [selectedDX removeObject:myMutArray[indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I've also tried it in in a single didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but the result is same.

Comment: allCodeLabel is type of string array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 if([selectedDX containsObject:allCodeLabel[indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
```

It works for me.Hope it helps :)

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin If you use the code from my question and also implement this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. It works perfectly. All the three answers are correct.

Comment: I know it is cell reuse issue but for large arrays instead of using different cell identifier and affecting memory,this seems easier.

Comment: @TalhaCh apologies I mis read this answer, i thought it was the same and one below. This is correct. One of the other answers suggesting only code inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Do you set the accessory type correctly when you return the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? It looks to me that you only set the accessory when the user taps on a cell but this is not enough.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [...]

    if ([selectedDX containsObject:myMutArray[indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Your cells are reused when you scroll in your table view. So one cell is reused for more than one of your items. This means the accessory is also reused. So when you scroll and don't remove the accessory from the cell it will still have the checkmark.

You could also reset the accessory in the `prepareForReuse` method in a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass

Comment: I understand and this seems the right way to do it. can you show in code please

Answer (score 1):

you can handle it like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   WCategoriesTableViewCell* cell = [tableView
                              cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to address the issue, the issue is about cell reuse. Setting it via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not enough

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin it can and enough bro   :)

Comment: Its not, the issue being caused is when the cell is reused, inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. As the user is scrolling up and down its reusing an instance and the position is getting lost. Adding this extra code when a user taps a cell is going to have no effect at all while the screen is scrolling

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin i know bro , you say completely correct but i had try it before and it can  handle the problem :) 
but in some situation required to handle in cellforrow!